# Remove warning about ansicon from "rake cucumber"

Tags: cucumber, warnings

When you run any rake task with cucumber installed on a machine that doesn't have ANSICON installed, you get the following message:

```
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon) to get coloured output on Windows
```

When running locally I like using ANSICON, but when used within the build server I don't care about that - and I don't want to see that warning there. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can actually remove the warning itself. I do not like installing a bunch of garbage just for the sake of having a green word. So, to remove the warning:

**1.** Locate the Cucumber installation in gems directory (it's in the Ruby installation directory). For me it was: lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\cucumber-1.2.0

**2.** In the cucumber-1.2.0\lib\cucumber\formatter directory of the Cucumber installation find the file **ansicolor.rb**

**3.** Locate the line:

> STDERR.puts %{*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon) to get coloured output on Windows}

and add # in front of it to comment it out:

> **#** STDERR.puts %{*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon) to get coloured output on Windows}

The line number was 14 for my version of Cucumber.

**4.** Save the file and you're done

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. The project is long gone by now, but I'm sure this will help others and I really appreciate the answer.

Comment: Yesp, I thought you may not use it - after seeing the question date. I did add it for future references, because the question was in the first Google results after I searched for solution :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

1. Download and unzip the file from http://adoxa.altervista.org/ansicon/
2. open cmd and navigate to the unzipped folder
3. Navigate to x64 (if you have a 64 bit machine) otherwise navigate to x86
4. Type ansicon.exe -h and you will get help of this command
5. Execute 'ansicon.exe -i' to install and add ansicon to your Windows
6. Run your cucumber 0.10.0 test and you should 
   get the coloured output result on Windows

Comment: Thanks, but that only works in the console, so doesn't actually solve my problem.

Comment: if this ansicon thing was packaged as a ruby gem it might be OK but for those of us trying to get work done it's just an annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add an exception to you spec_helper.rb? Or perhaps try adding a tag which you filter on when using rake?