# Ansicon and cucumber: 'Ruby interpreter (CUI) 1.9.3p194 [1386-mingw] has stopped working'

Tags: .net, ruby, cucumber

When installing ansicon v.1.3.2 and running a cucumber feature file, I get the following output:

`Ruby interpreter (CUI) 1.9.3p194 [1386-mingw] has stopped working`

When uninstalling ansicon and running cucumber I get the test running without coloured output.

Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem and i didn't found how to solve it yet.
But [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019013/remove-warning-about-ansicon-from-rake-cucumber) you can see how to remove the ansicon from cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with ansicon, after doing the steps below I haven't had any further problems.

1. Place the ansicon.exe file into your `Ruby193\bin` directory
2. Navigate there and install ansicon with `aniscon -i`
3. Run cucumber